# How to get result array from mysql in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

How to get result array from mysql in PHP ?
here is my code

```
$company = $_POST["company"];
$query = $this->db->query("Select id from users WHERE company like '$company'") ;
$user_id = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
print_r ('$user_id');
```

here error message

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   object given

can anyone fix my code ??

Comment: whats `$this->db->query`? is this from a `CI` object? use the proper fetching method `->get()` not the vanilla `mysqli`

Comment: @Ghost forgot to mention, I'm using Codeigniter

Comment: use the proper methods provided by CI, why in the world would you mix up bare mysqli functions in return values from CI objects. just be faithful and use CI methods all through out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use codeigniter query builder:-

```
$company = $_POST["company"];
$query = $this->db->query("Select id from users WHERE company like '$company'") ;

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    echo $row->available_fields;
}
```

Don't mix mysql with codeigniter query builder classes. Refer this link for better understanding https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html